# Django admin ignores has_delete_permission

Tags: python, django

I have simple project on Django 1.11.13, that uses ordinary Django's admin module. Staff user can not delete object while is permitted (has_delete_permission returns always true).

models.py:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.IntegerField("Value", blank=True, null=True)
```

admin.py:

```
@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return True

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return True
```

I created user and logged in. He can create MyModel object (as expected), can edit (as expected), but can not delete!!

That's what I see if I try to delete it:

> Deleting the selected my model would result in deleting related
>   objects, but your account doesn't have permission to delete the
>   following types of objects:
>
> ```
> my model
> ```

What am I doing wrong? How should I give permissions to delete MyModels to ordinary staff user?

Answer (score 0):

There's also a user `has_perm` check going on which will return False, because permissions aren't handled the normal way. You can MonkeyType around it, in my case there's a check if the user is staff and is active, but you can offcourse always `return True`

```
def override_user_has_perm(self, *args):
    return self.is_staff and self.is_active

User.add_to_class('has_perm', override_user_has_perm)
```